# @TransactionalEventListener is never being called in Spring Framework 4.2

Tags: spring, event-listener, transactional

I am implementing `@EventListener` from Spring 4.2 and it works fine.  When I try to implement a `@TransactionalEventListener` it never gets called.

The ApplicationListenerMethodTransactionalAdapter makes the check:

```
if(TransactionSynchronizationManager.isSynchronizationActive())
```

and it is always false so it skips running the event because it says it is not in a transaction.

The code for the event listener is simply:

```
@TransactionalEventListener()
public void handleTransactionalAddEvent(Event event)
{
    logger.info("Add Event: {}");
}
```

The code which publishes the event is as follows:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public Order addToOrder(String username, Long orderId)
{
    Order order = getOrder(orderId, username);

    publisher.publishEvent(new Event(order, Event.EventType.ADD));

    ... Code to do stuff to the order ...

    updateOrder(order);
    return order;
}
```

If I change the `@TransactionEventListener` to just be `@EventListener`, or I add the `fallbackExecution` attribute it will run fine, but with the `@TransactionEventListener` it never gets called.

Comment: Try the Spring JIRA, 4.2 isn't even a milestone or release candidate only build-snapshots so they can have problems. Also are you sure you have your transactions setup correctly.

Answer (score 4):

I found out that we had a custom ApplicationEventMulticaster which was conflicting with the transactional event listeners.  I removed it and now it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

@TransactionalEventListener is used when its method should be within the transaction.
If no transaction is running, the listener is not invoked at all since we can’t honor the required semantics.